# MariaDB Bitwise AND Of Hex String Literal

Tags: mysql, mariadb, hex, bit-manipulation

I want to `and` mask the result of mariadb MD5 method to return me only the first 32 bits of the 128bit value.

My issue is that the result of the MD5 function is a varchar and I cannot `and` it unless its a integer.

I have tried to use the CONV function but that returns only as a 64 bit number so all my results are INT_MAX, an example of that query is.

```
SELECT MD5(A.Country), CONV(MD5(A.Country),16,10), A.Country
 FROM Analytics A
```

Which returns

```
+--------------------------------+--------------------------+-------+
|MD5(A.Country)                  |CONV(MD5(A.Country),16,10)|Country|
+--------------------------------+--------------------------+-------+
|8f14e45fceea167a5a36dedd4bea2543|18446744073709551615      |7      |
|c81e728d9d4c2f636f067f89cc14862c|18446744073709551615      |2      |
|c81e728d9d4c2f636f067f89cc14862c|18446744073709551615      |2      |
|c81e728d9d4c2f636f067f89cc14862c|18446744073709551615      |2      |
|c81e728d9d4c2f636f067f89cc14862c|18446744073709551615      |2      |
+--------------------------------+--------------------------+-------+
```

What is the correct way to convert this varchar into a integer so I can then bitwise and it or is there a way to forego the integer conversion entirely and bitwise and the varchar instead.

Comment: So where is the bitwise code? What is the problem

Comment: Why don't you just extract the hex characters you need, without any conversion to int? So with  `left` or `right` depending on which characters you want to keep.

Comment: The problem is when you try and do `& 2^32 or (1<<31)` It wont give you the correct result because the result of the CONV is wrong, if you see all the retuls of the CONV column are the same even if the hash is different

Comment: Are you saying just get the first 8 characters and not bother with bitwise anding?

Comment: What version of MariaDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> or is there a way to forego the integer conversion entirely and bitwise and the varchar instead.

Yes: 32 bits is 8 hex characters, so you can do

```
select left(md5(a.country), 8)
from analytics a
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select CONV(LEFT(MD5(2233), 8), 16,10);
```

Will give you, effectively, and `INT UNSIGNED`.

`MD5()` give you 32 hex digits.
`LEFT(..., 8)` gives you the first 8; you could pick some other subset.